# Will I have to publish appcompat v7 with my project apk?

Tags: java, android

In my project, I am using the actionbar and libraries which extend from that; this meaning that there is the project 'appcompat v7' auto created.

My question is.

When I submit my app for publishing, will I also have to include the 'appcompat v7' project, as well as the project apk I am sending for publishing. Or do I simply send my project off an nothing else?

Answer (score 0):

You can't publish `project`. You can publish `apk` file. This file will contain all necessary classes and interfaces. So it will contain support library classes as well.

Comment: Ah ok, so the only thing I will need to upload is the APK file. And the apk will include the app compat v7?